# Как долго может длиться запрет на возможность задавать вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, блокировка

Как долго можно сидеть в бане (запрет на задание вопросов) и как улучшить статистику аккаунта?

1. Была ли у вас ситуация с баном на этом сайте?
2. Как вы исправили ситуацию? Что вы делали? Стоит ли вообще стараться?
3. Как долго можно просидеть в бане?

Пожалуйста, поделитесь своим мнением здесь, для меня это действительно очень важно.

Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: 1) Да 2) В справке написано что искупить свои злодеяния ты можешь только хорошими ответами ... 3) Отвечал на вопросы, а затем у меня случился рецидив 4) Вам решать ... 5) Тут круче ...  По прошествии времени на волю не отпускают искупление можно найти только в ответам на вопросы ... P.S. может для меня вести новый знак как рецидивист ... ? :))

Comment: Уточнил заголовок, потому что тут есть ещё другой вид бана, когда совсем учётку блокируют и можно только читать.

Comment: Пора бы каноничный вопрос на эту тему нам уже сделать =/

Comment: Непонятно, почему создание новой учетки не (однократное) решение.

Answer (score 10):

Лично у меня только недавно было снято ограничение (вчера).

*Отвечу на ваши вопросы:*

1) Да.

2) Так получилось, что связался с модерацией сайта (совершенно случайно, просто оставлял тревогу на чужом вопросе) и они мне посоветовали прочитать и отредактировать вопросы, которые я уже ранее удалял, также полностью их переосмыслить и красиво оформить, чтобы люди могли понять суть и ответить на них. Также была речь о том, чтобы попросил тех, кто ставил минусы - убрать их, но я так и не понял, как, например, узнать кто поставил минус.

3) Вечность(лично у меня был). Он полностью бессрочен, советую не торопиться с разбаном, а вносить импакт в общество, делать правки, писать дельные комментарии, ответы.

Когда был забанен, то на этот момент было около 150 (может, меньше) репутации, сейчас получилось улучшить до 411. Ответы хорошие давать тяжело, а правки делать не так уж и трудно, мой совет: редактируй свои прошлые вопросы и вытаскивай их из удалённого, если таковы имеются(меня именно это и спасло). Хочу добавить, что бан мне помог понять как правильно составлять вопросы, что является очень важным для этого сайта и реальной жизни, потому что надо уметь доносить свою мысль.